# Automating Cross-Browser Testing Using Selenium RC

Tags: cross-browser, automation, selenium-rc

I am trying to use Selenium RC to automate `cross-browser` testing.  I need to automate testing `IE7, 8 and 9`.  These browsers aren't installed on my machine.  I have a cross-browser testing tool called `Multi-Browser Viewer` installed on my machine, which has made the said browsers available to me as virtual browsers, located in the folder `C:\ProgramData\Multi-Browser Viewer`.  I would like to know how to use Selenium RC to access these browsers.  I mention the deprecated RC, as opposed to the WebDriver, because the vendor of Multi-Browser Viewer recommends using RC with their software.

Answer (score 0):

use the custom browser as following

```
*custom "Path to executable of browser"
```